# VB6 Window 7 Not able to set objects

Tags: vb6-migration

Same code working in windows XP when it  migrated to Windows 7, it's not working

If err.Number > 0 Then not working

```
Public Function Add(Key As String, ObjectType As String,  AddNew As Boolean, Delete As Boolean, Expand As Boolean, Collapse As Boolean, Search As Boolean) As ChildWindow

  Dim objNewMember As ChildWindow

  On Error Resume Next
  Set objNewMember = Me(Key)

  If err.Number > 0 Then
    Set objNewMember = New ChildWindow

    objNewMember.Key = Key
    objNewMember.ObjectType = ObjectType
    objNewMember.AddNew = AddNew
    objNewMember.Delete = Delete
    objNewMember.Expand = Expand
    objNewMember.Collapse = Collapse
    objNewMember.Search = Search

    mCol.Add objNewMember, Key
  End If

  Set Add = objNewMember
  Set objNewMember = Nothing
End Function
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Is there an error?

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?451770-RESOLVED-Err-Object-unrecognized-in-VB-6-0